# Syncing rushes from location record into Pro Tools 10 workflow help

Tags: sync

I've been getting a lot of jobs where the I get an offline edit done elsewhere and a hard drive with the location recordings dumbed on my desk for me to sync. So far my working method has been to do this manually and matching the takes to the offline provided...extremely time consuming.

Can anyone please advise me on an automated way that they know of doing this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maggot's "Assemblerator" or Sounds in Syncs "EdiLoad" both do what you need if you can get an EDL.

Answer (score 1):

If youre looking to sync video with separate audio in a standalone, I believe DualEyes is what youre looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 52 of the Protools 10 reference guide gives an explanation about the workflow with field recorders. Is really simple and fast and you don't need any additional software.
OR Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz9e9LuIdXU : Production Sound Workflow with Pro Tools - AGENT MX-Z3RO

Comment: Actually if he's getting an embedded OMF from FCP chances are the metadata will get stripped out so there's little chance of using the onboard matching features in my experience - although it IS a shifting target with things changing all the time and many variables

Comment: While that's true, there are ways of getting stuff out of FCP (specifically Automatic Duck) that can retain the metadata, IF it has been properly maintained on entry. Of course that can be a big IF. However if it is done correctly I can vouch for the efficiency of the PT workflow... 22 Eps into a series and it still hasn't let me down. Much easier than the old "Post Conform" days! 

Answer (score 0):

Its the picture editing department that is supposed to do the syncing.
Ask them to export you an OMF or an AAF, and import session data from that file, every region will (should....)synchronize, and make sure they have a academy leader at the front of the video, to make sure it does sync.

It that won't happen @ColtonRybus said it best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Colton and Filipe for your suggestions,  will have a look at Dual eyes